# How to select/call the stored functions in sakila database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 10 and pgAdmin-4 for learning postgreql. I am using the Sakila database.

My question is how do I select/call stored function correctly?

I tried out one stored function on the Sakila database,

```
 SELECT inventory_in_stock(10)
```

without any problem.

However when I tried another,

```
SELECT get_customer_balance (3,NOW());
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  function get_customer_balance(integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT get_customer_balance(3,NOW());
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 8
> ```

Comment: Should be: `SELECT get_customer_balance (3, now()::timestamp);`

Comment: I tried it back got back this error

ERROR:  function if(boolean, interval, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF((rental.return_date - rental.rental_d...
                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: It seems the database you can download from [PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) contains an invalid function. The jOOQ author has published a corrected version of that function: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/Sakila/postgres-sakila-db You can [download the schema script](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/Sakila/postgres-sakila-db/postgres-sakila-schema.sql)  and extract the corrected function definition and re-created that function in your database

Comment: Hey! It seems to be working now! Thank you so much!